# jQuery run same function on click button or onchange dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have following code which is working fine on click button but i also want it to execute on change event of my drop down list. which is

```
 $("select#search_status").change() //i want same execution for it do i need to duplicate whole code ?


$('.search-btn-cls').click(function () {
    var search_text = $('#search_text').val();

    search_val = true;
    initiatePagination();
    // ajaxSortPaginationSearch();
    // show_per_page();
    // getpagination();

    if (search_text.length > 2 || search_text.length < 1) {
        ajaxSortPaginationSearch();
        show_per_page();
        getpagination();
    } else {
        alert('Please enter minimum 3 serach character.');
        $('#search_text').focus();
    }

});
```

Comment: somebody posted this answer $('.search-btn-cls').on("click change",function () {  and now he removed. is that not the right solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using anonymous function for event handling, create a function and call it in both cases i.e on click and on change.

```
// Create a function.
function handleDropdown() {
    var search_text = $('#search_text').val();

    search_val = true;
    initiatePagination();
    // ajaxSortPaginationSearch();
    // show_per_page();
    // getpagination();

    if (search_text.length > 2 || search_text.length < 1) {
        ajaxSortPaginationSearch();
        show_per_page();
        getpagination();
    } else {
        alert('Please enter minimum 3 serach character.');
        $('#search_text').focus();
    }

}
// Now call the function.
$('.search-btn-cls').click(handleDropdown);
$("select#search_status").change(handleDropdown);
```

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Call both events with same function that you want to execute.
$('.search-btn-cls').click(main);
$('.search-btn-cls').change(main);

        function main(){
            var search_text = $('#search_text').val();

            search_val = true;
            initiatePagination();

            if (search_text.length > 2 || search_text.length < 1) {
                ajaxSortPaginationSearch();
                show_per_page();
                getpagination();
            } else {
                alert('Please enter minimum 3 serach character.');
                $('#search_text').focus();
            }
        }
```